# How to change the value of link rel tag

Tags: javascript, dom

My CMS uses

```html
<link rel="prev" href="/t/119152/page-18" />
<link rel="next" href="/t/119152/page-20" />
```

to link to previous and next thread pages. I want to add rel=preftech value to these links using javascript.

I tried

```js
<script>
document.querySelector("link[rel=prev]").setAttribute("rel", "prev prefetch");
document.querySelector("link[rel=next]").setAttribute("rel", "next prefetch");
</script>
```

and

```js
document.querySelector('link[rel=prev]').rel = 'prefetch';
document.querySelector('link[rel=next]').rel = 'prefetch';
```

but none of these seem to update it.

Also, where should the script tag should ideally be placed for it to work?

Comment: People normally put the script tag at the bottom of the page whether its in a HTML tag or file since that will load after all HTML has loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both techniques work as you can see here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTNL>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="prev" href="/t/119152/page-18" />
  <link rel="next" href="/t/119152/page-20" />
</head>
<body>



<script>
  document.querySelector('link[rel=prev]').rel = 'prefetch';
  document.querySelector("link[rel=next]").setAttribute("rel", "next prefetch");

  console.log(document.querySelectorAll("link")[0].outerHTML);
  console.log(document.querySelectorAll("link")[1].outerHTML);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```